# different data types associated data skew

Tags: performance, hive

Today I read one article about the hive tuning. One paragraph is as follows:

Scene: user_id in the user table the field user_id INT, log table field both of type string type int. When two tables in accordance with the user_id Join operation, the default Hash operation will be allocated int id, this will cause all records of the string type id assigned to a reducer.

Solution: numeric type is converted to a string type

```
select * from users a 
left outer join logs b 
on a.usr_id = cast (b. user_id as string)
```

Can anybody give me some more explanation about the above opinion, I really cannot understand the words the author describe. Why "this will cause all records of the string type id assigned to a reducer." happened? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For starters you did not copy and paste / transcribe the original properly. Here is the more likely wording:

> this will cause all records of the string type id assigned to a
>   **single** reducer.

The reason that would happen is that the conversion of string to int **without the `cast`** is probably turning it to **0**. Therefore the hashing will put all of the id's into the same partition for the 0 values.